# How to save as object files to different directories in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I hava an RDD below:

```
Array(
(0, "xx"),
(1, "xx"),
(2, "xx"),
(1, "yy")
)
```

I want to save it to different directories by the key. For example, to create 3 files in those directories:

```
0/part-00000 // xx
1/part-00000 // xx and yy
2/part-00000 // xx
```

Through `saveAsHadoopFile` and `MultipleTextOutputFormat`, I can do it in **text format**. However, this RDD contains huge complex data. Saving it in **compressed format** may be better, like what `saveAsObjectFile` does.

`MultipleSequenceFileOutputFormat` may help me realize it, but how to use it correctly?

---

**EDIT :**

I have tried this to do it in text format:

```
.saveAsHadoopFile(outputPath, classOf[Any], classOf[Any], classOf[MultiOutputFormat])
```

```
  class MultiOutputFormat() extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {

    override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = {
      NullWritable.get()
    }

    override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = {
      key.asInstanceOf[Int] + "/" + super.generateFileNameForKeyValue(key, value, name)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of spark are you using?

Have you tried something like

```
.repartition(3).saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

or

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setClass(FileOutputFormat.COMPRESS_CODEC, classOf[GzipCodec], classOf[CompressionCodec])
```

?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the version clearly...... I edited the question to show what I have tried.

Comment: Instead of bothering with MultiOutputFormat, have you simply tried : `rdd.repartition(3).saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output", classOf[GzipCodec])`

Comment: I have tried this. But it can't write to different directories... Maybe I could move files to different directories by myself after `saveAsTextFile`? I think it's workable...

Comment: `.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output", classOf[GzipCodec])` was an answer to "i want compression". If you want multiple directories, simply filter your rdd and save each time! for example `rdd.filter(d=>d._1=="x").saveAsTextFile("/path/to/x", classOf[GzipCodec])` and then `rdd.filter(d=>d._1=="y").saveAsTextFile("/path/to/y", classOf[GzipCodec])`

Comment: I need write to 16 different directories. Will these `filter` and `save` makes it much slower than one `save`?

Comment: Hard to tell if it will be faster or slower. You always get surprised... I think there's only one way to know : try! Take care to .cache() your rdd before you apply the 16 filter+cache ... And let us know how it goes!